# How to convert string to color in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, parsing, colors, integer

I want to convert the string to color but I can't,

**My Code**

```
String color = "0xffff5252";
Color result= Color(int.parse(color, radix: 16));
print("$result");
```

** I get the following problem**

`Invalid radix-16 number (at character 1) 0xffff5252`

Comment: *the string starts with "0x", "-0x" or "+0x", in which case the radix is set to 16 and the "0x" is ignored.* Seems it works fine without `radix`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below

```
String color = "0xffff5252";
Color result= Color(int.parse(color));
print(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

if youe motive is to define a color by first defining into string and then by parsing it, then there's a much simpler way to define color,

```
    const Color primary = Color(0xFF92A3FD);
const Color secondary = Color(0xFF9DCEFF);
const Color thirdColor = Color(0xFFC58BF2);
const Color fourthColor = Color(0xFFEEA4CE);
const Color bgTextField = Color(0xFFF7F8F8);

const Color facebookColor = Color(0xFF3b5998);
const Color googleColor = Color(0xFFDB4437);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this **hexToColor** function:

```
 // Construct a color from a hex code string, of the format RRGGBB.
 Color hexToColor(String code) {
 return Color(int.parse(code.substring(1, 6), radix: 16) + 0xFF000000);
 }
```

This worked for me to store a color & use it as a profile avatar color.